# android studio storing information?

Tags: android, android-studio

How Android Studio store informations about my PC or my IP?
Lets say that i compile and build an Android project in a PC and then transfer that project to another PC and run it there.

Do you think there is still some kind of catches or stored libraries that store my info of my old computer?

Comment: That would depend upon how exactly you "transfer that project to another PC". If you transfer over only the files necessary to build the project -- the sort of information that programmers would put into version control -- then there should be nothing about your specific PC in there.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache

Comment: check the `.idea` folder its not humanly readable but that holds the info you are looking.

Comment: Thank you. I transfer the whole project folder with everything (Gradle files + lib + src and build files).

Answer (score 0):

If running Linux, there is a folder inside each project called `.idea` all the information needed to migrate and run project in a new Andrioid Studio Environment is there.

Comment: I am runinng with Mac and couldnt find the .idea folder.

Comment: it's hidden, be sure to show Hidden file and folders